# Have Regex Find Absent Word

Tags: regex, missing-symbols

I need to find entries which begin with @ and don't have word "keyword" before the next @ within this example:

```
@something
something
something
keyword
something
something

@something
something
something
something
something

@something
something
something
keyword
something
something
```

So this search string would point me to the second example. Does someone know how to do this with Regex?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The following regex seems to be working:

```
@\w+(?![^@]*\bkeyword\b[^@]*)
```

### Demo

Explanation:

```
@\w+             match a @label
(?!              provided that we DON'T see ahead
    [^@]*        any text without another @label
    \bkeyword\b  which also has the "keyword"
)
```

Comment: Thank you for that, especially for the explanation. Since my @ something words are all different (@ book, @ article and so on) for some reason this reges was marking all those words so I removed \w from it and this worked!

Comment: \w means `[A-Za-z0-9_]`; so every ASCII word(except `unicode flag is used`) comes there @eklisiarh; Why you have to remove it?

Comment: @mandy: because it was showing every entry in my bibliography. No idea why.